# Problems using evaluation with 'undefined' property

Tags: javascript

I am using the evaluation with undefined to check if my component is created or not. When I pass a date that must alert 'false' the alert shows it the right way, so 'false'. But when I pass a date that must return true I get an error: 'undefined is not an object'(evaluating 'mark['2019-04-15'].dots'). Why this statement function only for defined ones?

```
alert(typeof mark['2019-04-15'].dots === "undefined");
```

Comment: `mark['2019-04-15']` is `undefined`, and trying to access the property `dots` on that will give rise to your error.

Comment: thank you. That's right

Answer (score 0):

`mark['2019-04-15']` is `undefined`, and trying to access the property dots on that will give rise to your error.

You could e.g. check if `mark['2019-04-15']` has a value first.

```
if (mark['2019-04-15']) {
  alert(typeof mark['2019-04-15'].dots === "undefined");
}
```